# How to wrap an environment (e.g. frame) in a tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, environments, tcolorbox, beamerarticle

**My question**

How do I wrap the `frame` environment in `beamer` to have it in a `tcolorbox` in `\mode<article>` ? (and not just the title as below)

[image]

**Context**

I use `beamer` and `beamarticle`.

I'd like to highlight the frames in a `tcolorbox` when I use `\mode<article>`.
It enables me to see what is in the notes vs the shorter version that should be in the frames.

I understand I need to change the `\setbeamertemplate` with the right key for the frame environment.
I'd like what's in the frame to be a wrapped in a tcolorbox in `\mode<article>`
(not just the title as in MWE with an error).

I'd like also to have the Title(+Subtitle) as the title of the `tcolorbox`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\mode<article>
{
\setbeamertemplate{frame begin}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colback=red!20,
            colframe=red!60,
            arc=4mm,
            title={\insertframetitle \emph{\insertframesubtitle}},
            coltitle=red!50!black, 
            fonttitle=\bfseries\scshape,
            detach title,
            before upper={\tcbtitle\par}
            ]
            }%
\setbeamertemplate{frame end}{\end{tcolorbox}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    {Title of the frame}
    {Subtitle of the frame}
        
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first
        \item Second
        \item third
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27308/194703) is a way to add boxes around the frames. To add a `tcolorbox` *environment* seems to be more tricky.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat merci for the link. I start playing with it and it already does not compile :/

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I did not test it. Since it most likely did compile when it was written, an update must have broken it. (I only know one user who will most likely immediately know what is going on. You can find her [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex).)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Merci for the check, just as if you've just given me the name of the doorman of a bar I can't get in :)

Comment: What do you mean you can't get in? You can certainly access that site, can't you? (Let me mention that there is in principle a way to turn all frames in `tcolorboxes`: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545597/194703). You can make it work for the above scenario. However, there will always be scenarios in which it fails.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I got in a just post my question. but your "(I only know one user who will most likely immediately..." made me think you gave me like a secret door for an exclusive thing. SamCarter seems to be the one :)

Comment: Bingo. ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: I did some tests on my side, but with your style modifications, you use `\insertframtitle/\insertframetitle` before the actual start of the `frame` so `\frametitle/subtitle` are not defined yet, leading to and empty `\tcbtitle`. Moreover, it seems the `tcolorbox` has trouble with the `\begin{frame}{<frametitle>}{<framesubtitle>}` format see the below (not really an answer) proposal.

Comment: @BambOo Hi, take a look @ https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1089.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat do you want to post an answer from XYZ ?

Comment: @JeT There are folks like us, then there are some wizards ....

Comment: @BambOo I think you're the next one in the wizard's club....

Comment: I think "my" answer is mainly samcarter's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified code which shows the colorbox, but not the subtitle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\mode<article>
{
\setbeamertemplate{frame begin}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colback=red!20,
            colframe=red!60,
            arc=4mm,
            title={\insertframetitle \emph{\insertframesubtitle}},
            coltitle=red!50!black, 
            fonttitle=\bfseries\scshape,
            detach title,
            %before upper={aaa \tcbtitle\par}
            ]
            }%
\setbeamertemplate{frame end}{\end{tcolorbox}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title of the frame}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle of the frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first
        \item Second
        \item third
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]